# jquery control a dropdown from a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" name="artist" value="Yes">
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

how can i select option 1 when checkbox is checked and option All when checkbox is unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Working Example (jsfiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZLpT/1/)

```
$('#checkbox_1').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#dropdown').val(1);
    }
    else {
        $('#dropdown').val('All');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#checkbox_1").change(function() { 
    $("#dropdown").val(
        $(this).is(":checked") ? 
            "1" : 
            "All"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I broke it down a bit for clarity, but this should do the trick.

```
$("#checkbox_1").click(function() {
    var checked = $("#checkbox_1").attr("checked");
    var selectVal;
    if (checked)
        selectVal = 1;
    else
        selectVal = "All";
    $("#dropdown").val(selectVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$('#checkbox_1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#dropdown').val('1');
    } else {
        $('#dropdown').val('All');
    }
});
```

is(':checked') is just one of many ways to check if a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ( $('#checkbox_1').is(':checked')){
        $('#dropdown').val('1');
 }else{
     $('#dropdown').val('All');
 }
```

edit: this would not be a 'live' function. which other members have already provided code for